# Calculate frequency of words from column with CSVs in cells

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a column in my sheet which contains form submitted values via a Google Forms checkbox. This produces a comma separated values (CSV) list in the sheet due to multi-selection in the form. An example:

[image: screenshot]

I want to calculate the frequency of each "tag" being used. To produce something like:

[image: screenshot]

I found this formula (credit to @AdamL), which was fantastic for calculating the frequency of individual words in a full concatenation of a whole column:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ";B3:B);" ")&{"";""});"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 10 label Col1 'Word', count(Col2) 'Frequency'";0))
```

However, I couldn't find a way to modify it to split into generated fields by a comma (or comma and space) rather than just a space (which, of course, produces the single words in each field). Hope that makes sense.

Tried replacing the delimiter in Join from " " to "," and to ", " - no joy :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> modify it to split into generated fields by a comma (or comma and space) rather than just a space

It's both the `JOIN` and the `SPLIT` function you need to touch for that. Instead of `SPLIT(JOIN(" ";B3:B);" ")`, try:

```
SPLIT(JOIN(", ";B3:B);", ")
            ^^         ^^
```

This way, the `JOIN` will put cells together with a two-character delimiter, `", "`, which is the same delimiter you are getting from the form. Then `SPLIT` will take every `", "`, both those from the `JOIN` and those from the form, and break apart individual terms. The space between words will survive.

And you'll have:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(", ",B2:B),", ",false)&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 10 label Col1 'Word', count(Col2) 'Frequency'",0))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How about having this query case insensitive? How would you do it?

Comment: @leontalbot - you should ask that as a new question, which refers to this answer for context & attribution. Others are more likely to find it and benefit from it that way.

Comment: `...` `JOIN(", ",LOWER(B2:B))` `...` Let's note that `PROPER()` systematically capitalize the first letter, that's even better...